# React Native Router Flux BackgroundImage

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

is it possible to move the picture behind the bar at the top.
I provided a 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYIdx.jpg) . 
Thank you guys!

Edit 1: Once you see the tabbar + one example for a scene. This is in an Router Component. 
Next code fragment is taken from on of the components rendered in those scenes.

```
   class Courses extends React.Component{ render(){
return(
      <Image
        source={require('../../../assets/backgrounds/Navigation/kurse.jpg')}
        style={{resizeMode: 'stretch', height: 100, width: 430}}
      />



<Scene
         key="tabbar"
         tabs
         tabBarStyle={{backgroundColor: '#252525'}}
         activeBackgroundColor="#CEECF5"
         inactiveBackgroundColor="white"
         >


             <Scene key="Start" icon={HomeIcon} >
               <Scene
                key="Dashboard"
                component={Dashboard}
                titleStyle={styles.nagivationBarTitleStyle}
                title="Start"
                rightButtonImage={SettingIcon}
                onRight={()=>{Actions.Settings()}}
                navigationBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
                 />
```

Comment: Please share the written code as it would be helpful to other developers.

Comment: @Sateesh Did add the code

Answer (score 0):

you will have to create your own navbar component and give it backgroundColor:"transparent" and hide navbar from router flux stack that way you will see image content behind your navbar check example below.

```
render(){
return(
 <ImageBackground
        resizeMode="cover"
        source={Images.loginBg}
        style={styles.container}
      >

         <Navbar title="Login" rightTitle="Signup" onRight={this.onRight}/>

        <View style={styles.dividerFirst}>
          <Image source={Images.title} style={styles.titleImage} />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.dividerSecond}>
          <FacebookButton
            onPress={this.onFacebook}
            title="Login With Facebook"
          />
          <View style={styles.spacer} />
          <GradientButton onPress={this.onDeviceMode} title="Practice Mode" />
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
);
}
```